# Publishing Weather Data under Creative Commons / Peer Production License

Tags: api, releasing-data, weather, metadata

I am from a volunteer at FSHM (Free Software Hardware Movement, Puducherry, India).

As a part of our community project, we have been working on building a weather station using Freedom Hardware. We are experimenting various things, and are building prototypes for the same. The aim of this project is to build a low-cost distributed community based local weather stations.

As a part of this project, we also were exploring ways to keep the weather data open to all, by releasing the data we capture, in either Creative Commons / Peer Production License.

Upon our exploration, we ended up finding, openweathermap.org, who promised to keep the weather data open (**We want to post data, not consume it**). When we started exploring their api's for posting, we discovered it doesn't work. Our data was never uploaded. Tough we have contacted them on the same, we also wanted to explore other options or online website, where **weather data** would be kept open and accessible to all.

Please do let us know, if you have come across or used anything.

PS : We want the data to be available under Creative Commons / Peer Production License.

PPS : If there really is none, then we are left with no choice but to write one. Do also let us know if somebody has already started anything similar or already half way through.

Comment: Welcome at Open Data Stackexchange! I hope you will find a satisfactory answer to your api question or a suggestion for another data archive here.

Answer (score 3):

try contacting the open science data cloud; at the bottom of this link is a contact email regarding submissions:
https://www.opensciencedatacloud.org/publicdata/

you also can get free hosting for organizations on datahub.io
last resort -> github (which is a pretty awesome last resort)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Open Database Licence (ODbL) from Open Knowledge Foundation is what you're looking for : http://opendefinition.org/licenses/odc-odbl/
It is the licence under which all OpenStreetMap data is released, it is an equivalent to CC-BY-SA but written especially to address data issues.
See the OpenDefinition website to discover more OpenData-valid licences : http://opendefinition.org/licenses/

Comment: Hey Roux, Thanks for the response, 
But my question was not about a license, but more about where should I publish the data . Please do read the question again .

Comment: Hey, sorry I misunderstood that indeed, I thought you were trying to identify a good licence for your data.
Regarding hosting there are plenty of options, but it really depends on your volume and frequence of updates

Comment: If it's not too big, some open opendata catalogues for instance among the different ckan websites should be happy to host your data. Otherwise you might want to host it on a server and domain name yourself and just reference it on opendata catalogues by pointing to your data url.

Comment: Ya, We dont really mind hosting our own, which we are keeping a last option. The  problem I see with hosting out own is people, dont discover it. But if we can all push a data to a common place, a place where people wanting data come come, like one stop shop, was first want we wanted to explore. Hosting outown site is still an option that we want to explore last.
@albert 's datahub looks interesting for hosting for me.

Comment: I didnt know ckan, so exploring that too. Thanks for the info.